# Is open() writing to my file?

Tags: python, pickle

I really don't have much to say here except my terminal output

```python
matthew@archey [03:13:31 PM] [~/code] 
-> % python3         
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:35:40) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20171224] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> f=open("pokemon.pkl", "wb")
>>> pickle.dump({}, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> exit()
matthew@archey [03:15:23 PM] [~/code] 
-> % cat pokemon.pkl 
�}q.%                                                                                                                               matthew@archey [03:15:27 PM] [~/code] 
-> % python3 pokedex.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pokedex.py", line 8, in <module>
    pokemon = pickle.load(f_read, "rb")
EOFError: Ran out of input
matthew@archey [03:15:37 PM] [~/code] 
-> % vim pokedex.py 
matthew@archey [03:15:52 PM] [~/code] 
-> % cat pokemon.pkl 
matthew@archey [03:16:02 PM] [~/code] 
-> %
```

All of the code:
Just a note - this adds pokemon to the `pokemon.pkl` file

```python
import pickle

# pokedex pokemon appender

f_read = open("pokemon.pkl", "rb")
f_write = open("pokemon.pkl", "wb")

pokemon = pickle.load(f_read)

f_read.close()

try:
    while True:
        p_name   = input("Name: ")
        p_type   = input("Type: ")
        p_height = input("Height: ")
        p_weight = input("Weight: ")
        pokemon[p_name] = [p_type, p_height, p_weight]

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pickle.dump(pokemon, f_write)
    print("Exiting...")
```

So this is what I did:

- Created the pickle file
- Viewed my pickle file
- Ran my code. It errored out and said the file 'ran out of input'
- Viewed the pickle file again. There was nothing there!

Please help!

Comment: What is the content of `pokedex.py`?

Comment: `pickle.load(f_read, "rb")` ??? `f_read` is already a handle. Something is wrong here.

Comment: @Kevin it appears to be a wrapper for an API https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pokedex.py

Comment: @n1c9: Nope, that file [does not unpickle stuff](https://github.com/PokeDevs/pokedex.py/blob/master/pokedex/pokedex.py).

Comment: added the content of the file - @Kevin it is for adding to a pickle file

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
f_write = open("pokemon.pkl", "wb")
```

opens the file for writing *and deletes all of the file's contents*. Move this line to the place where you actually want to write to the file (just before `pickle.dump`).